# Magento VAT Number Invalid

Tags: magento

Magento return 'VAT Number is Invalid' every time event I entered valid VAT Number.

[image]

I checked my VAT number [here](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/) and it's working I got all information with my name. please help why Magento return Invalid.

For Example my Vat Number is CZ42555751 and i entered 42555751.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To validate a VAT number, Magento internally calls the webservice at http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl

As defined in `_createVatNumberValidationSoapClient` in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php`

```
/**
 * WSDL of VAT validation service
 *
 */
const VAT_VALIDATION_WSDL_URL = 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl';
```

From a call to `checkVatNumber` in the same class.

```
/**
 * Send request to VAT validation service and return validation result
 *
 * @param string $countryCode
 * @param string $vatNumber
 * @param string $requesterCountryCode
 * @param string $requesterVatNumber
 *
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
public function checkVatNumber($countryCode, $vatNumber, $requesterCountryCode = '', $requesterVatNumber = '')
{
```

These are called by the `_validate` function of the ValidatevatController.php file (`Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_System_Config_ValidatevatController`) when you click the validate button.

Looking at the example you gave, it appears that the code is invalid.